# Laravel 8 and Docker Desktop - MySQL problem (MYSQL_PASSWORD cannot be used for the root user)

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I am really having hard time trying to set mysql_1 container up and running.

So, I installed Laravel 8 just by instructions, first downloaded Docker Desktop, set WSL properly and everything works fine except MySQL.

I installed Laravel from Windows Terminal using:

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
cd example-app
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

Everything works fine (I can access app on http://localhost/), I can edit files using VSCode etc.
But I get this kind of error trying to start MySQL container:

```
2021-03-22 11:02:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-03-22 11:02:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-03-22 11:02:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.
2021-03-22 11:02:21+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: MYSQL_USER="root", MYSQL_PASSWORD cannot be used for the root user

Use one of the following to control the root user password:

- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Does anybody know what should I change to make this works?
P.S. Also I checked port 3306, everything is fine (Windows Firewall doesn't block port).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch your MYSQL container, you should pass an environment variable with `-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=yourpassword`

It is necessary for MYSQL. You can also use the other variables they offer you to use, they each have their particularities, but they all define the password for the `root` user. Which is a requirement.

Comment: Sorry, I suppose that this question is not so smart, but how to provide something that I did not set, because I didn't set root password anywhere..

Comment: When you write `-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=`dangerous` for example, you tell to Mysql to add the password `dangerous` to the user `root`. That is how you set it. It is a requirement by Mysql. You can find more [here in the section about environment variables](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)